# Union and join clause returned duplicate value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my code where it returns duplicate value. I've tried to tweak the code  but still did not returned the result that I desired. There are five scenario that I have to cater. Need advice or tips from u guys.

```
@BatchID int
--date smalldatetime

AS  

--DP to LN

select 
a.batch_id,
a.effective_dt,
a.from_acct_no,
e.title_1,
b.iso_code as 'from_currency',
a.from_crncy,
a.to_crncy,
a.to_acct_no,
f.title_1,
c.iso_code as 'to_currency',
a.to_posted_amt,
a.status,
a.rej_reason,
d.short_text,
a.from_description,
a.from_amt,
a.batch_tran_id,
d.error_text

from 

gb_batch_tfr_trans a,
ad_gb_crncy b,
ad_gb_crncy c,
pc_ov_error d,
dp_acct e,
ln_acct f

where 

a.from_crncy=b.crncy_id
and
a.to_crncy=c.crncy_id
and
d.error_id=*a.rej_reason
and 
a.status in ('rejected')
and 
a.from_acct_no*=e.acct_no
and
a.to_acct_no*=f.acct_no
and
a.batch_id= @BatchID

union all
```

--GL TO GL

```
select 
a.batch_id,
a.effective_dt,
a.from_acct_no,
g.description as 'Fromacc',
b.iso_code as 'from_currency',
a.from_crncy,
a.to_crncy,
a.to_acct_no,
h.description as 'Toacc',
c.iso_code as 'to_currency',
a.to_posted_amt,
a.status,
a.rej_reason,
d.short_text,
a.from_description,
a.from_amt,
a.batch_tran_id,
d.error_text

from 

gb_batch_tfr_trans a,
ad_gb_crncy b,
ad_gb_crncy c,
pc_ov_error d,
gl_acct g,
gl_acct h

where 

a.from_crncy=b.crncy_id
and
a.to_crncy=c.crncy_id
and
d.error_id=*a.rej_reason
and 
a.status in ('rejected') 
and
a.from_acct_no*=g.acct_no
and
a.to_acct_no*=h.acct_no 
and
a.batch_id= @BatchID

union all
```

---GL to DP

```
select 
a.batch_id,
a.effective_dt,
a.from_acct_no,
g.description as 'Fromacc',
b.iso_code as 'from_currency',
a.from_crncy,
a.to_crncy,
a.to_acct_no,
h.title_1 as 'Toacc',
c.iso_code as 'to_currency',
a.to_posted_amt,
a.status,
a.rej_reason,
d.short_text,
a.from_description,
a.from_amt,
a.batch_tran_id,
d.error_text

from 

gb_batch_tfr_trans a,
ad_gb_crncy b,
ad_gb_crncy c,
pc_ov_error d,
gl_acct g,
dp_acct h

where 

a.from_crncy=b.crncy_id
and
a.to_crncy=c.crncy_id
and
d.error_id=*a.rej_reason
and 
a.status in ('rejected')
and
a.from_acct_no*=g.acct_no
and
a.to_acct_no*=h.acct_no
and
a.batch_id= @BatchID

union all
```

--DP to GL

```
select 
a.batch_id,
a.effective_dt,
a.from_acct_no,
g.title_1 as 'Fromacc',
b.iso_code as 'from_currency',
a.from_crncy,
a.to_crncy,
a.to_acct_no,
h.description as 'Toacc',
c.iso_code as 'to_currency',
a.to_posted_amt,
a.status,
a.rej_reason,
d.short_text,
a.from_description,
a.from_amt,
a.batch_tran_id,
d.error_text

from 

gb_batch_tfr_trans a,
ad_gb_crncy b,
ad_gb_crncy c,
pc_ov_error d,
dp_acct g,
gl_acct h

where 

a.from_crncy=b.crncy_id
and
a.to_crncy=c.crncy_id
and
d.error_id=*a.rej_reason
and 
a.status in ('rejected')
and
a.from_acct_no*=g.acct_no
and
a.to_acct_no*=h.acct_no 
and
a.batch_id= @BatchID

union all
```

--GL to LN

```
select 
a.batch_id,
a.effective_dt,
a.from_acct_no,
g.description as 'Fromacc',
b.iso_code as 'from_currency',
a.from_crncy,
a.to_crncy,
a.to_acct_no,
h.title_1 as 'Toacc',
c.iso_code as 'to_currency',
a.to_posted_amt,
a.status,
a.rej_reason,
d.short_text,
a.from_description,
a.from_amt,
a.batch_tran_id,
d.error_text

from 

gb_batch_tfr_trans a,
ad_gb_crncy b,
ad_gb_crncy c,
pc_ov_error d,
gl_acct g,
ln_acct h

where 

a.from_crncy=b.crncy_id
and
a.to_crncy=c.crncy_id
and
d.error_id=*a.rej_reason
and  
a.status in ('rejected')
and
a.from_acct_no*=g.acct_no
and
a.to_acct_no*=h.acct_no
and
a.batch_id= @BatchID
```

Comment: Why do you have `c` and `c++` tags?

Comment: Please don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) - always explicitly qualify your joins.  For one thing, it may help spot where you've dropped/added a condition.  Also, not every DB supports the syntax you're using.  Which queries are returning duplicates?  Include table layouts/sample data for each of the problem scenarios (and things like unique constraints), and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'union' instead of 'union all' if you don't want duplicates.

And judging from the structure of your query, your table design has serious problems.

Comment: i've tried and the duplicate are lesser.thank you.But,i need to considered if any both to_dep_loan or from_dep_loan account number is invalid.e.g.one batch id will include all the transaction been made on that day based on the 5 scenario.if the rej_reason is because the acccount is invalid it doesn return duplicate but if the rej_reason are others it will return duplicate.thank you so much for your help